# how can I add multiple rows in database from a single form?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

I'm setting up a roster web application using Laravel, and I need a form where to input all the fields and then store them to the database, everything works fine when I use tinker or if I submit a single row, but when I try to submit the whole form only the last row is read.

this is the `rota.blade.php` file

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => 'RotaController@store', 'method' => 'POST', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']) !!}

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">Name</th>
            <th scope="row">Sunday</th>
            <th scope="row">Monday</th>
            <th scope="row">Tuesday</th>
            <th scope="row">Wednesday</th>
            <th scope="row">Thursday</th>
            <th scope="row">Friday</th>
            <th scope="row">Saturday</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <!--
        * create a loop to iterate through each instance in the weekly rota database
        * and create a row for each one; in case the username coincides with the name in the rota
        * add class="active" to each row, so it is easier for the user to identify its own row
    -->
        @csrf
        @foreach ($users as $user)
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">
                    {{$user->first_name}}
                    <input name="user_id" type="hidden" value="{{$user->id}}">
                    <input name="week_no" type="hidden" value="{{$currWeek}}">
                </th>
                <th scope="row">
                    {{Form::text('sunday', '', ['class' => 'form-control'])}}
                </th>
                <th scope="row">
                    {{Form::text('monday', '', ['class' => 'form-control'])}}
                </th>
                <th scope="row">
                    {{Form::text('tuesday', '', ['class' => 'form-control'])}}
                </th>
                <th scope="row">
                    {{Form::text('wednesday', '', ['class' => 'form-control'])}}
                </th>
                <th scope="row">
                    {{Form::text('thursday', '', ['class' => 'form-control'])}}
                </th>
                <th scope="row">
                    {{Form::text('friday', '', ['class' => 'form-control'])}}
                </th>
                <th scope="row">
                    {{Form::text('saturday', '', ['class' => 'form-control'])}}
                </th>   
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    {{Form::submit('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary'])}}
</tbody>

</table>    
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

and this is `RotaController@store`:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
     //validation
     $this->validate($request,[
        'user_id' => 'required',
        'sunday' => 'required',
        'monday'=> 'required',
        'tuesday'=> 'required',
        'wednesday'=> 'required',
        'thursday'=> 'required',
        'friday'=> 'required',
        'saturday'=> 'required',
        'week_no'=> 'required'
    ]);

    //create a field
    $rota = new Rota;
    $rota->user_id = $request->input('user_id');
    $rota->week_no = $request->input('week_no');
    $rota->sunday = $request->input('sunday');
    $rota->monday = $request->input('monday');
    $rota->tuesday = $request->input('tuesday');
    $rota->wednesday = $request->input('wednesday');
    $rota->thursday = $request->input('thursday');
    $rota->friday = $request->input('friday');
    $rota->saturday = $request->input('saturday');
    $rota->save();

    $users = DB::table('users')->orderBy('first_name', 'asc')->get();
    return view('admin.admin-rota')->with('users', $users);

}
```

I tried `dd($request)` and it actually gets only the last set of input fields,
I guess I have to loop through them but I don't know how. Does anyone have any suggestion on what to try? thanks a lot for any feedback, I'm still very new using this framework.

Comment: looks like input names are the same for each row. Try to use user id to make them unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would group form data by users.

```
    @foreach ($users as $user)
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">
                        {{$user->first_name}}
                        <input name="users[{{$user->id}}][id]" type="hidden" value="{{$user->id}}">
                        <input name="users[{{$user->id}}][week_no]" type="hidden" value="{{$currWeek}}">
                    </th>
                    <th scope="row">
                        {{Form::text("users[$user->id][sunday]", '', ['class' => 'form-control'])}}
<th scope="row">
                        {{Form::text("users[$user->id][monday]", '', ['class' => 'form-control'])}}

                </tr>
            @endforeach
        {{Form::submit('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary'])}}
    </tbody>
```

in the controller you will have array with data for each user.
Then your controller may look like this:

```
 public function store(Request $request)
{
     //validation
     $this->validate($request,[
        'users.*.user_id' => 'required',
        'users.*.sunday' => 'required',
        ...
    ]);
    foreach($request->get('users') as $userData){
       $rota = new Rota;
       $rota->user_id = $userData['user_id'];
       $rota->week_no = $userData['week_no'];
       $rota->sunday = $userData['sunday'];
       ...
       $rota->save();
    }
    //create a field


    $users = DB::table('users')->orderBy('first_name', 'asc')->get();
    return view('admin.admin-rota')->with('users', $users);
}
```

Comment: Thanks this  works fine, only thing is that for some reason it didn't let me add variables such as $user->id inside the Form:: class, I solved it by changing it to a normal <input> field, so it's no problem, but I was wondering if you know why this happens.

Answer (score 0):

You can append an index to each of the input's name, and hold a hidden input to store the collection count.

```
@php
    $idx = 0;
@endphp

@foreach ($users as $user)
<tr>
    <th scope="row">
        {{$user->first_name}}
        <input name="user_id_{{$idx}}" type="hidden" value="{{$user->id}}">
        <input name="week_no_{{$idx}}" type="hidden" value="{{$currWeek}}">
    </th>
    <th scope="row">
        {{Form::text('sunday_' . $idx , '', ['class' => 'form-control'])}}
    </th>
    <th scope="row">
        {{Form::text('monday_' . $idx, '', ['class' => 'form-control'])}}
    </th>
    <th scope="row">
        {{Form::text('tuesday_' . $idx, '', ['class' => 'form-control'])}}
    </th>
    <th scope="row">
        {{Form::text('wednesday_' . $idx, '', ['class' => 'form-control'])}}
    </th>
    <th scope="row">
        {{Form::text('thursday_' . $idx, '', ['class' => 'form-control'])}}
    </th>
    <th scope="row">
        {{Form::text('friday_' . $idx, '', ['class' => 'form-control'])}}
    </th>
    <th scope="row">
        {{Form::text('saturday_' . $idx, '', ['class' => 'form-control'])}}
    </th>   

    @php 
        $idx++;
    @endphp
</tr>
@endforeach
{{-- holds numbers of users count --}}
<input type="hidden" name="user_count" value="{{$users->count()}}">
```

In the controller, loop over the amount of user's using variable `$user_count` that we got from blade file. Each data variable will have the appended index, and you can then correspond the right data that you entered from blade file. Note that the validation here is being done on each object per iteration. If you would like to **VALIDATE ALL** data before saving, make another `foreach` with the validate before saving the data.

```
for ($i=0; $i < $request->user_count; $i++) { 
       //validation
    $this->validate($request,[
        'user_id_' . $i => 'required',
        'sunday_' . $i => 'required',
        'monday_'  . $i=> 'required',
        'tuesday_'  . $i => 'required',
        'wednesday_'  . $i=> 'required',
        'thursday_'  . $i => 'required',
        'friday_'  . $i=> 'required',
        'saturday_' . $i=> 'required',
        'week_no_' . $i=> 'required'
    ]);

    //create a field
    $rota = new Rota;
    $rota->user_id_{$i} = $request->input('user_id_' . $i);
    $rota->week_no_{$i} = $request->input('week_no_' . $i);
    $rota->sunday_{$i} = $request->input('sunday_' . $i);
    $rota->monday_{$i} = $request->input('monday_' . $i);
    $rota->tuesday_{$i} = $request->input('tuesday_' . $i);
    $rota->wednesday_{$i} = $request->input('wednesday_' . $i);
    $rota->thursday_{$i} = $request->input('thursday_' . $i);
    $rota->friday_{$i} = $request->input('friday_' . $i);
    $rota->saturday_{$i} = $request->input('saturday_' . $i);
    $rota->save();
}
```